# Can Laravel query builder connection have 2 arguments?

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

After I executed the query below Laravel display an error saying the enterpriseDB.employee_detail does not exist. Both enadopodDB and enterpriseDB are two different databases.

```
        $query = DB::connection('enadopodDB','enterpriseDB')
                    ->table('affected_employee')
                    ->join('enterpriseDB.employee_detail', 'enterpriseDB.employee_detail.employee_detail_id', '=', 'affected_employee.employee_id')
                    ->select('affected_employee.*', 'enterpriseDB.employee_detail.full_name')
                    ->get();

        var_dump($query);
```

If the query builder is wrong, please suggest a solution for it.

Comment: No, it cannot. why are you trying to join over two databases. It is possible with a raw query if it is the same server and the same user for the 2 db. But in my opinion this should not be done at all

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the database name for all tables. You can try in this way if you have both databases on the same connection and are set to default.

```
$query = DB::table('database1.table1 as dt1')->leftjoin('database2.table2 as dt2', 'dt2.ID', '=', 'dt1.ID');        
$output = $query->select(['dt1.*','dt2.*'])->get();
```

I have tried on my localhost it's working.